# Existence condition of root of $f(x)=x$

Tags: real-analysis

I begin with this:

> If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [a,b]$ is continuous and $|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$ for all $x\neq y$, then the equation $f(x)=x$ has exactly one root.

The problem is not very hard and I solved it. Then I wonder if this problem is true or not:

> If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$ for all $x\neq y$, then the equation $f(x)=x$ has exactly one root.

With one more hypothesis $f$ is bounded, the above one becomes true. However, I could not find any function which is a counter-example for the original one.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any counter-example for the problem $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? If not, how can we prove it?
2. Besides $f$ is bounded, can we find any different hypothesis to add (if necessary) to lead to the conclusion?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Some counterexamples include:

   $$ f_1(x) = \begin{cases} 2 & x\le 1 \\
   x+1/x & x \ge 1 \end{cases} $$
   or
   $$ f_2(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2} $$

   In both cases there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=x$.
2. You need to add hypotheses that ensure that $f(x)=x$ has at least one solution. In the $f:[a,b]\to[a,b]$, the Intermediate Value Theorem applied to $f(x)-x$ between $a$ and $b$ takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a counterexample by setting $f(x)=x-g(x)$ where $g$ is any positive, strictly increasing function that doesn't increase too fast. Something like $g(x)=\frac\pi2+\arctan x$ should work well.

If you have $|f(x)-f(y)|\le L|x-y|$ for a constant $L<1$, there will alays be a fixed point of $f$. This is Banach's fixed point theorem, but in this context it is easy to prove: Fix $y=0$ in the inequality and show that $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} x-f(x)=\pm\infty.$$